# When I save rendered image with transparent background I get white png picture, blender 3.0

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I guys, I have my "volumetrics" scene in blender 3.0 and when I render image with transparent background in Eevee render engine  in viewport it has "check board" shown but when I save it its all white.
I have set in render properties under "Film" to transparent I have set color "RGBA" and File format to PNG under Properties. What Im doing wrong ?

here is my .blend file https://we.tl/t-DbNMkuwWnY

Comment: When I rebaked everything and hit render, this is what I got
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAZmj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAZmj.png) Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes I got same result but try to save it is it with white background ? @Aswin

Comment: Oh yea, I didn't try saving it
you're right, it's kinda invisible
but when you put it on a 100% black background, I could see it slightly
I'm not sure I can help, but I'll try looking into it